# Domian & Subdomain based routing with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

I want to make an application that will render different pages based on subdomains. 
Like for the subdomain `sub1.domain.com/home, sub2.domain.com/home & sub3.domain.com/home` it will render 3 different pages. For this purpose I can use express-subdomain but can I make it work the same way for 3 different domains?

suppose that I have 3 domain `domain1.com, domain2.com & domain3.com` which is pointed to the same nodeJS application and I want to serve different response based on domain.

I am using Express, but I am more interested in how to do that with raw nodeJS server.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with using libraries when they come handy? The trade-off seems reasonable in your case (using `Express` and `express-subdomain`).

Comment: express-subdomain is fine for subdomain wise routing but what about domain wise routing?

Comment: You can always check the `host` header in combination to other libraries or writing your own middle-ware.

Comment: thanks, i should have tried that before asking.